# Не получается пользоваться готовыми решениями в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня не получается скомпилировать готовые программы в apk файлы в Android Studio.
Я начал изучать Java, разобрался с синтаксисом и некоторыми операциями и дальше пока не пошел, т. к. задача того пока что не требует.
Вкратце, я нашел готовые решения в GitHub, хотел их модифицировать, но работе с ними в Android Studio (скачал-распаковал-запустил) возникают ошибки.
Ошибки доходят до абсурда.

1. Например, строчка выглядит import package xxxx и читается программой
   нормально, но если я эту строчку напишу вручную (буква в букву) -
   она уже подчеркнута красным.
2. В готовой программе переменные и классы импортированы, но часть из
   них выделена красным в самом теле, и IDE их не понимает.
3. Часто вижу ошибки вроде такой, при открытии готовых проектов :
   "*Compilation is not supported for following modules: GSDemo, app.
   Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and
   Android-Gradle modules in one project.*" . Меняются только названия
   и типы модулей, которые есть в файле программы.

Я конечно же, не с пустого места открыл и начал работать с Android Studio. Цель моих изысканий - новое приложения для дронов DJI. Поэтому, я начинал с изучения туториалов по их SDK https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/GSDemo-Google-Map.html
И уже на этом этапе я не мог побороть тьму ошибок, хотя там все разжевано донельзя (там просто нужно повторить код, буквально скопипастить).
Мой порядок действия при открытии проекта таков: открываю, синхронизирую грэдл, например он указывает - что нужно импортировать Maven Google в проект - ок, сделал, провел Refactor. Жалуется на то, что sdk android указан низкий - поменял. И собственно, дальше ошибки которые я описал выше, которые не позволяют пойти дальше.

Может быть мне старую IDE поставить? Неделю я долбил все это и уже руки опускаются (оттого что я готовую программу в APK файл не могу вывести).
Если это какая то матчасть, и я должен как то настраивать IDE для каждого проекта индивидуально - прошу, ткните носом.

Answer (score 0):

куча ошибок получается при разных версиях проекта и компилятора. Я так же свои старые проекты не мог открыть после обновления студии. Вобщем, качаешь проект и в студии нажимаешь не "открыть проект", а "импортировать проект"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]